# read a multi tier csv file in python

Tags: python, list, file-io

I need to read the following data out of a text file;

```
[L02]
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,g,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,g,g,g,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,g,g
g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,g,g
[L01]
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
```

I can read a single block as a csv file but I don't know how to read each file as a separate list

The output I want is to have arrays/lists for each block with the block contents as the list elements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script that demonstrates how to break down the problem into reusable steps (functions) and performs the transformation your need.

```
import itertools
import operator
import re
import csv
import pprint

class TaggedLine(str):
    """
    Override str to allow a tag to be added.
    """
    def __new__(cls, val, tag):
        return str.__new__(cls, val)

    def __init__(self, val, tag):
        super(TaggedLine, self).__init__(val)
        self.tag = tag

def sections(stream):
    """
    Tag each line of the stream with its [section] (or None)
    """
    section_pattern = re.compile('\[(.*)\]')
    section = None
    for line in stream:
        matcher = section_pattern.match(line)
        if matcher:
            section = matcher.group(1)
            continue
        yield TaggedLine(line, section)

def splitter(stream):
    """
    Group each stream into sections
    """
    return itertools.groupby(sections(stream), operator.attrgetter('tag'))

def parsed_sections(stream):
    for section, lines in splitter(stream):
        yield section, list(csv.reader(lines))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('data.csv') as stream:
        for section, data in parsed_sections(stream):
            print 'section', section
            pprint.pprint(data[:2])
```

Save your file as 'data.csv' and the script will run on your data with this output:

```
section L02
[['g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'w',
  'w',
  'w',
  'w',
  'g',
  'g'],
 ['g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'w',
  'w',
  'w',
  'w',
  'w',
  'g',
  'g']]
section L01
[['d',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd'],
 ['d',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd',
  'd']]
```

Comment: Whoa Thanks!
I din't expect the entire code! All I need to to is format the output.
Thanks again.

Comment: TaggedLine could be more simply declared using namedtuple:  `TaggedLine = namedtuple("TaggedLine", "line tag")`.  Not sure what inheriting from `str` buys you.

Comment: Inheriting from str means that the tagged line is still usable as a string, so you can treat it just like the original line (or sequence of lines). If you used namedtuple, code that handles the sequence has to know that it's getting a tuple and not a string and handle it accordingly. In this particular example, a tuple would have worked just fine, but since `sections` takes a stream of lines and generates a stream of lines, it's more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [numpy](https://numpy.org/), you could read the file into a numpy array. `comments='['` tells `np.genfromtxt` to ignore lines that begin with `[`. The `reshape` method places each 16x16 block in its own "layer".

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.genfromtxt('data.csv',comments='[',delimiter=',',dtype=None)
arr=arr.reshape(-1,16,16)
```

You can access the nth layer with `arr[n]`.