# Reading a multi-section text file into muliple arrays

Tags: python

I have a multi-section text file that is essentially thousands of collections of data with the following format:

```
psxy -R -Jm -N -G0/19/255 -K -O <<eof>> image.ps
   64.0100  28.0100
   64.0400  28.0100
   64.0700  28.0100
   64.1000  28.0100
   64.1400  28.0100
   64.1700  28.0100
   64.2000  28.0100
   64.2300  28.0100
   64.2600  28.0100
   64.2600  28.0400
   64.2600  28.0700
   64.2600  28.1000
   64.2600  28.1400
   64.2600  28.1700
   64.2600  28.2000
   64.2600  28.2300
   64.2600  28.2600
   64.2300  28.2600
   64.2000  28.2600
   64.1700  28.2600
   64.1400  28.2600
   64.1000  28.2600
   64.0700  28.2600
   64.0400  28.2600
   64.0100  28.2600
   64.0100  28.2300
   64.0100  28.2000
   64.0100  28.1700
   64.0100  28.1400
   64.0100  28.1000
   64.0100  28.0700
   64.0100  28.0400
   64.0100  28.0100
eof
 #   1
```

The first line calls the utility GMT (Generic Mapping Tools), where each of these sections is plotted in the file `image.ps` as a colored polygon with a color given by RGB values in the `-G` tag. Each section ends with an `eof` and a label (`#    1`).

Basically, I would like to be able to have two separate arrays, one for individual RGB values split from the `-G` tag, and the other each separate set of polygon vertices. The end goal is to plot these polygons (without using GMT) using various matplotlib/basemap tools.

Is this possible? I have seen in other posts that it is [possible for simpler formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925551/read-a-multi-tier-csv-file-in-python), but I am somewhat new to Python.

Thank you.

Comment: Reading and parsing this input file would be a piece of cake in python. Its not very clear what you you want done with the arrays once they're read in. Do you want to maintain the association between each polygon and its RGB values?

Comment: Ha, maybe it's easier than I thought. I basically want to do something like `Polygon(xy,fillcolor=RGB)`, where `xy` is the collection of vertices and `RGB` is the associated RGB tuple. So yes, I would like to maintain the RGB values for each set of points. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
import re

polygons = []

with open('inputfilename') as datafile:
    for line in datafile:

        if 'psxy' in line:
#This is the beginning of a new polygon. Start with an empty set of points
#and parse out the color, and store it in a tuple
            points = []
            m = re.search('-G([\d\.]+)/([\d\.]+)/([\d\.]+) ', line)
            r,g,b = m.group(1,2,3)
            r = int(r)
            g = int(g)
            b = int(b)
            color = (r,g,b)

        elif 'eof' in line:
#This is the end of a polygon. Take the list of points, and the last color
#put them in a tuple and append that to the list of polygons
            polygons.append((points, color))

        elif '#' in line:
#do nothing with this line
            pass

        else:
#This is a pair of x,y coordinates. Turn them into floats, put them in a tuple
#and append the tuple to the list of points for this polygon.
            x,y = line.split()
            x = float(x)
            y = float(y)
            points.append((x,y))


#Now to plot the polygons
for poly in polygons:
    drawPolygon(poly[0], poly[1])
```

This is a very simple example with no error checking.
It will break if the input file syntax does something unexpected.
It may also have typos and other bugs.
If it breaks you can keep all the pieces. :)

Comment: Awesome! I think it was going about matching the `psxy' tag, and the regexp magic on the RGB values that was tripping me up. Thank you!